# Updating Wordpress plugin admin panel footer text

Tags: plugins, admin, footer, text

The Wordpress admin backend displays the following footer text for each page of the admin panel:
'*Thank you for creating with Wordpress*'.

What is the cleanest way to update this text for a particular plugin page only ?

Currently I have added a filter for the 'admin_footer_text' hook, however, this has the effect of updating ***all*** page footers on the backend, not just those specific to my plugin.

Is it a case of using the 'admin_footer_text' hook, and adding some conditional checking around which admin panel page is being called? Or is there a cleaner, more direct hook I should be using?

Comment: Should everybody guess the plugin name?

Comment: I don't see how the particular plugin name is relevant to the question ?

Comment: May be it has a hook to modify it's footer. Now content yourself with generic code.

Comment: It's my own custom plugin...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
// check the plugin admin page
if( is_admin() && isset( $_GET['page'] ) && 'PLUGIN-NAME' == $_GET['page'] ) { 

    // replace the footer with empty string
    add_filter( 'admin_footer_text', '__return_empty_string' );

}
```

Comment: If so, please accept the answer.

Comment: I am waiting for any further submissions, as I would like to know if theres a cleaner way of achieving the same outcome. If not, I will accept your answer.

Comment: Depending on where you put this, you should check `isset( $_GET['page'] )` before evaluating its value; i.e. `if( is_admin() && isset( $_GET['page'] ) && 'PLUGIN-NAME' == $_GET['page'] ) {`

Comment: Sure, you are right. I gave the main idea, not working example, as there are many unknowns in the question. I'll edit the answer.